# Args with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, args

I need help to pars args in a method inside my controller.

i have a form for sending my parameter to  function

```
    <form method="post" action="/">
<input type="text" id="query" placeholder="file to search ...">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="fetch!">
    </form>
```

and in my controller :

```
@RestController
public class mainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(Model model) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
        model.addAttribute("query");
        String res = drive.checkFile("query");

        return res;
```

the query is a string send via the form. and return res in the same view.
Do you have any tips?

thanks you very mutch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring MVC It will be like this:

```
@Controller
public class mainController {

@PostMapping( "/index")
public String index(@ModelAttribute FormDataObjectClass object) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");

    //model.addAttribute("query");
    String name = object.getName();
    String address = object.getAddress();
    String res = drive.checkFile("query");

    return res;
}
```

Here no need of passing `Model` as argument as we need a custom Object(FormDataObjectClass) to be used.
Create a class `FormDataObjectClass`  as per you data in HTML form/JQuery post method

Comment: hi, thx for your answer, i dont understand what is  name and adress? i just need a String param send by the form via html. for instance, in my form i write = googlename , and in my controller googlename is the string param of checkfile method

Comment: the address will be `<BaseURL>/index` and your method parameter will be will simiar to  `formObject,getParam()`. refer https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial